# screen: ‘-S sessionname’ vs. ‘-t name’

Tags: gnu-screen, session

What's the difference between `screen -S <sessionname>` and `screen -t <name>`? It seems that both assign a name to the newly created screen, which can be reattached using this name.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`-t <name>` sets the default title for newly created shells in your screen session.  If you invoke `screen -t MyShell` then type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>w</kbd>, you will see them at the bottom of your terminal:

```
0$ MyShell  1-$ MyShell  2*$ MyShell
```

You can change each title of shells by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>A</kbd>.

`-S <sessionname>` sets the name of the screen session you create.  You can see existing sesions in the system with `-ls`, then attach one of them using that session name by `-r <sessionname>`.  This feature is usefull especially when you have to maintain multiple screen sessions simultaneously.

```
$ screen -ls
There are screens on:
    23834.pts-4.myserver    (06/01/15 12:38:11) (Detached)
    23812.MySession (06/01/15 12:34:24) (Detached)
2 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-yaegashi.

$ screen -r MySession
```

You can change the name of current session by typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> then enter `sessionname <newsessioname>`.